# plasma tag itself is too generic, should be compounded and split into TV and workspace

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request, tags

As things stand right now, [plasma](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/plasma) is ambiguous.  Questions labeled with it refer both to plasma TVs and to the KDE graphical environment, and this doesn't seem correct to me.

I suggest deleting the generic [plasma](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/plasma) tag and replace it with [plasma-tv](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/plasma-tv) and [plasma-workspace](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/plasma-workspace) to better categorize entries.

Comment: This is the perfect place to point out this issue.

Comment: would (wouldn't?) plasma-workspace-kde be somewhat more precise?

Comment: Yes, I suppose that will deeply describe what is talked about, even if AFAIK the only Plasma Workspace around is the KDE one and so it may be redundant. Anyway, my point was to separate the generic "plasma" tag, and of course the how's are to be debated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm very much in favor of this.

[plasma-tv](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/plasma-tv) sounds fine. For the KDE workspaces, I'd prefer [kde-plasma-workspace](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/kde-plasma-workspace) or even just [kde-plasma](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/kde-plasma).

---

It's done. I went with [kde-plasma-workspace](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/kde-plasma-workspace). [plasma](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/plasma) is now a synonym for [plasma-tv](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/plasma-tv).

Comment: I think anything related to plasma-tv shouldn't be tagged as such.  I can't think of a situation that knowing the tag "plasma-tv" is helpful to the question at all.

Comment: @KronoS: Seems to me like it's just as legit as `CRT` and `LCD`. Wouldn't you agree?

Comment: IMO those should be burninated as well, but then again I'm pretty prejudiced against the lesser than detailed tags.  To me they're about as useful as `Microsoft` or `Apple` which give me absolutely no detail into the problem really.